# Hamster - Skin Infection

Tags: hamsters

I have a white dwarf hamster about 6 months old. Now I am pedantic about diet, it's environment and I check him daily. Water replaced regularly, bedding regularly. Overall he gets the same treatment I would expect if I could not do it myself.

I picked him up this evening and noticed under his belly a sort of brownish scab that sort of protrudes out slightly. It's not like a scab that we would get from falling, instead it has sort of "grown" outwards.

There is no sign of inflammation and his hair doesn't seem to be falling out.

I am not sure what I should do? I have Aloe Vera gel but it is from the pharmacy and I do not want to apply this if it will make the hamster sick.

Also, because I play with him daily, I honestly don't know how I missed this if it was already there yesterday, unless it's possible from hurting himself (which I can't see how) as there is nothing dangerous or sharp in his cage. To me it looks a little too sketchy to be a normal scab.

Here is an image of what is happening under his stomach.

[image]

I do think perhaps a vet may not be a bad call if it does not improve. I do want to try home remedies first though if anyone knows what this might be.

Thanks again!

Comment: My hamster has something on his stomach as well that looks very similar. Did your vet happen to say what could be done if it happened again? Is it dangerous if it’s not cleaned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If anyone is interested in an answer here. Took the little guy to the vet and it turns out that this was a is bit gunk inside the umbilical cord cavity which can happen from time to time. The vet cleaned him up with a little cotton swab and dettol (savlon) disinfectant. All came off. Skin looks good... So just a tip to hamster owners out there. Keep an eye on the tummy for build up in the middle. :-)